# vb.net copied rtf text not pasteable in notepad

Tags: vb.net, clipboard, copy-paste, rtf, plaintext

If I copy the `SelectedRtf`Content of an RTF box to the clipboard, the text isn't pasteable in a TextEditor like Notepad, only in a Rtf enabled one like WordPad.

```
Dim strClpTxt As String = txtResultsAll.SelectedRtf
Clipboard.SetText(strClpRtf, TextDataFormat.Rtf)
```

--> Paste possible in WordPad, but not in Notepad.

```
Dim strClpTxt As String = txtResultsAll.SelectedText
Clipboard.SetText(strClpTxt)
```

--> Past possible in WordPad AND Notepad, but without formatting.

However, if I copy the Content from WordPad by `Ctrl+C` it's pasteable in Notepad (of course, without formatting).

Is there a way to copy Rtf and plain text in VB.net?

Comment: You should use a [`DataObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dataobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) since that allows you to provide more than one format. (which will also be what Wordpad does (the multiple formats thing, not the DataObject thing, since it's not a .NET app))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `txtResultsAll.Copy()` it copy the selected text and works in both cases.